# Java Entity error - null primary key

Tags: java, jpa, entity, eclipselink, netbeans-platform

I have 2 entity classes: Shipvia and Route. My Shipvia is working fine. Route entity class is an exact copy of it, but of course tailored for the tablename and fields. Both classes are read using this method:

```
public class RetrieveResultList {

private static final EntityManagerFactory FACTORY = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("EntityLibraryPU");

    public static <T> List<T> retrieveResultList(Class<T> type) {
        EntityManager entityManager = FACTORY.createEntityManager();
        String tablename = type.getName(); // figure out table name from **type**
        Query query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(tablename + ".findAll");
        List<T> resultList = query.getResultList();
        entityManager.close();
        return resultList;
    }
}
```

My working entity class for Shipvia is here: http://pastebin.com/R53tNHyp

My entity class for Route is: http://pastebin.com/8f4L2Z62

Unless I made a mistake somewhere by missing a variable or field, I am not sure why I get the following error when trying to get the resultList from the above method.

I get the following error:

```
Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [EclipseLink-6044] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.0.v20110604-r9504): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException
Exception Description: The primary key read from the row [ArrayRecord(
ROUTE.ROUTEKEY => null
ROUTE.RUADD_DATE => null
ROUTE.RUADD_TERM => null
ROUTE.RUADD_TIME => null
ROUTE.RUADD_USER => null
ROUTE.RUCHG_DATE => null
ROUTE.RUCHG_NUMB => null
ROUTE.RUCHG_TERM => null
ROUTE.RUCHG_TIME => null
ROUTE.RUCHG_USER => null
ROUTE.ROUTE => null)] during the execution of the query was detected to be null.      
Primary keys must not contain null.
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Route.findAll" referenceClass=Route sql="SELECT ROUTEKEY, RUADD_DATE, RUADD_TERM, RUADD_TIME, RUADD_USER, RUCHG_DATE, RUCHG_NUMB, RUCHG_TERM, RUCHG_TIME, RUCHG_USER, ROUTE FROM ROUTE")
```

What's weird is that if I run the query above

```
SELECT ROUTEKEY, RUADD_DATE, RUADD_TERM, RUADD_TIME, RUADD_USER, RUCHG_DATE, RUCHG_NUMB, RUCHG_TERM, RUCHG_TIME, RUCHG_USER, ROUTE FROM ROUTE
```

It returns a perfect result. I am not sure where to start looking for an error!

Comment: Can you check and post the `CREATE TABLE` sql for the `ROUTE` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this sql will solve it

```
delete from ROUTE where ROUTEKEY is null
```

Comment: Well. That was simple D: Thank You! I am working with a FoxPro Database set, that has been in production for 20 years. I didn't even begin to think there'd be a null somewhere in the PK!! Your solution was simple and fixed the problem!

Comment: hope you didn't do that on production DB ;)